# Censored data without the indicator

Tags: survival

Can we talk about censored data without observing the indicator? Normally we observe $Z_i = T_i\wedge C_i,$ where $C_i$ is the time of censoring, and  $\delta_i = \mathbb{1}(T_i \leq C_i),$ the indicator of whether the observed time corresponding to disease recurrence or censoring. Can we find some censored data just by observing only $Z_i?$

Thank you

Comment: How could you distinguish censored data from non-censored data in that case?  In fact, if you have absolutely no knowledge about the indicators, then conceivably *all* the data could be censored. That leaves you being able to say a tiny bit--but not very much.